# Windows 7 Setup Stops After Booting and "Windows is loading files"

Tags: windows-7, installation

I created a bootable external hard drive with Windows 7 setup, it does boot, it does start loading files, as Windows says. "Windows is loading files..." and then it just stops on a screen with an image, which is Windows 7 default desktop I would guess.

I then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> which seems to work, so the administrator console starts, I tired to run setup.exe from there, and it did ran but when I click "Install Now" that window disappears and after 1-2 seconds it reappears. Any advice on this one?

Comment: I don't quite follow how you are installing it. It's not from DVD right?

Comment: external hard drive

Comment: Can you try a USB stick instead, created using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) or [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/download/en/)?